# Script returns offline for every ping

Tags: php

I have the script below, and it can ping any IP statically put in the file, but when I post to it it always fails.

```
<?php
$server = $_POST['ip'];
if (!$socket = @fsockopen("$server", 80, $errno, $errstr))
{
  echo "<font color='red'><strong>Offline!</strong></font>";
}
else 
{
  echo "<font color='green'><strong>Online!/strong></font>";


  fclose($socket);
}

?>
```

Comment: try: `(!$socket = @fsockopen($server, 80, $errno, $errstr))` but the code (with my IP) works.. So please can you post your HTML (form).. Or try putting an actual IP in instead of `$server = $_POST['ip'];` so it would therefore be: `$server = "IP....";

Comment: Your last closing strong tag is malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added several functions:

```
<?php
function port($Host, $Port = '')
   {
   if (strstr($Host, ':'))
      {
      if (strstr($Host, '/'))
         {
         $Output = substr($Host, strpos($Host, ':') +1, (strpos($Host, '/') -1) - strpos($Host, ':'));
         }
      else
         {
         $Output = substr($Host, strpos($Host, ':') +1);
         }
      }

   if ((isset($Output)) and ($Output != ''))
      {
      return $Output;
      }
   else
      {
      if ($Port != '')
         {
         return $Port;
         }
      }
   }

function server($Host)
    {
   if (strpos($Host, '//'))
      {
      $Host = substr($Host, strpos($Host, '//') +2);
      }

   if(strstr($Host,"/"))
        {
        $Host = substr($Host, 0, strpos($Host, "/"));
        }

   if(strstr($Host,":"))
        {
        $Host = substr($Host, 0, strpos($Host, ":"));
        }

    return $Host;
    }

    $Host = $_GET['ip'];
    $Host = server($Host);

    $churl = @fsockopen($Host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);

if (!$churl) { 
    echo("<div><b>Offline</b></div>"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    echo("<div><b>Online</b></div>"); 
    }



?>
```

Comment: So I would do $result = exec("/bin/ping -n 3 $server"...?

Comment: Yes! If you're on UNIX. Also, remove the other bracket from line 12, or copy my updated code.

Comment: Ok, but it now returns Online! on every ping. You can test it here: http://soocialize.net/server/s.php?ip=gjicjgijfgidhf

Comment: I deleted the second bracket, and updated the code, but to no effect.

Comment: Change $host to $server or recopy the code again, sorry for being so annoying ;P

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/soociali/public_html/server/s.php on line 10

Comment: Remove the extra bracket in the if.

Comment: '<?php
$server = $_POST['ip'];
$output = array(); // /bin/ping if you're on UNIX.
exec("ping -n 1 $server 2>&1", $output);
if (count($output) > 1) { // If the server is responding to a ping.
 $output = null;
  echo "<font color='red'><strong>Online!</strong></font>";
}
else
{
 $output = null;
  echo "<font color='green'><strong>Offline!</strong></font>";
}
?>'

Comment: `<?php
$server = $_GET['ip'];
$output = array(); // /bin/ping if you're on UNIX.
exec("ping -n 1 $server 2>&1", $output);
if (count($output) > 1) { // If the server is responding to a 
 $output = null;
  echo "<font color='red'><strong>Online!</strong></font>";
}
else
{
 $output = null;
  echo "<font color='green'><strong>Offline!</strong></font>";
}
?>`

Comment: Also, it's not $_POST, it's $_GET

Comment: Sorry, can you put this as an edited answer? I can't find where some of the lines end. Sorry!

Comment: Done! I've also added some functions.